# How do I set a semi transparent colour over a ACF background image?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-image, advanced-custom-fields

Exactly what it says in the title. How do I set a semi transparent coloured layer over an ACF background image?

I'm using an ACF image as a div background for a certain div box on a WP site. I need to have a black background colour set to x% transparency over the image but under the text.

I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I've tried adapting the code on this page (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity) but it breaks the image and throw up an error code.

Anyone know how to do this correctly please?
my css -

```
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 2em 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and my html -

````
<div id="residential_page_header_image_text" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('residential_page_header_image'); ?>);">
<p><?php if( get_field('residential_page_header_image_text_1') ): ?>
    <?php the_field('residential_page_header_image_text_1'); ?>
<?php endif; ?></p>
    <p><?php if( get_field('residential_page_header_image_text_2') ): ?>
    <?php the_field('residential_page_header_image_text_2'); ?>
<?php endif; ?></p>
    </div> ```
````

Comment: Always try to add a minimal working prototype. You can use `codepen.io` for that.

Comment: _"Exactly what it says in the title."_ - really ...? Where is the actual _background_ image then, I don't see any in the code you have shown so far.

Comment: My bad - I had missed out the top line of the html code. Now edited to show that.

Comment: Although you have shown there is a background image, you are just copying the php but this isn’t really a php question. It will be easier for us to debug if you could show a working snippet of the resulting html and css. Please put the snippet into the question not on an external site like codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this? Take a look.

```css
.acf-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.acf-image:before{content:''; position:absolute; inset:0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5)}
.acf-image img{object-fit:cover; height:100%; width:100%}
.acf-text{position: absolute; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%); text-align:center; left:0; right:0}
.acf-text p{color: #fff; font-size:17px;  }
```

```html
<div class="acf-image">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/220px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="">
<div class="acf-text">
<p>Lorem Ipsum<p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is pulling an image URL in there. I can do that but I need to pull the image from the custom fields. So if the image gets changed later on the page will show the new image without having to go into the coding and alter it that way

Comment: You just need to pick the value of the image from ACF field and put it in the img src . that way the structure will be same and you can upload the pic that you want. Unfortunately here PHP is not supported at all.. so i need to use the direct link of the image.

You can use it like this
<img src="<?php the_field('residential_page_header_image_text_1'); ?>" alt="" />

Comment: Glad to hear. You're Welcome.